# Using a period to separate volume and issue number of a journal article in biblatex-chicago

Tags: citing, biblatex-chicago

How can I tweak `biblatex-chicago` to use the format "`volume`.`number`" instead of "`volume`, no. `number`"?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{grohmann1929paragraphos,
    Author = {Grohmann, Adolf},
    Journal = {Byzantinische Zeitschrift},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {163--165},
    Title = {Zur Paragraphos},
    Volume = {30},
    Year = {1929}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\cite{grohmann1929paragraphos}

\end{document}
```

Current output is:

> Adolf Grohmann, "Zur Paragraphos," *Byzantinische Zeitschrift* 30, no. 1 (1929): 163–165.

I would like it to become:

> Adolf Grohmann, "Zur Paragraphos," *Byzantinische Zeitschrift* 30.1 (1929): 163–165.

Comment: Alex, what is your field of study? The modifications you have asked for so far match the requirements of `biblatex-sbl` (which I maintain). SBL style is based on Chicago style, but with some modifications. `biblatex-chicago` is a lot more mature than `biblatex-sbl` though. So I'd only recommend you take a look if you are actually working in biblical studies.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning `biblatex-sbl`. I didn't know about it! I am in an adjacent field (Byzantine and Middle Eastern history), so it makes sense that some journals ask for tweaks to Chicago that bring it closer to SBL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For removing the "no." before `number`, things are straightforward, as we can do this with a formatting directive:

```
\DeclareFieldFormat{journum}{#1}
```

The change in punctuation though requires we fiddle with the macro `cjournal+ser+vol+num`. I've chosen a patch for this, but you could also redefine it, changing the part of interest, it is not a long macro.

```
\xpatchbibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}{% search
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}{% replace
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit{\adddot}}
  {}{}% <success> and <failure>
```

The usual advice is however due. If you are choosing `biblatex-chicago` because you must comply with the Chicago Manual of Style, you should not be doing such tweaks, as the package is set to comply with it.

In full:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{grohmann1929paragraphos,
    Author = {Grohmann, Adolf},
    Journal = {Byzantinische Zeitschrift},
    Number = {1},
    Pages = {163--165},
    Title = {Zur Paragraphos},
    Volume = {30},
    Year = {1929}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareFieldFormat{journum}{#1}

\usepackage{xpatch}

\xpatchbibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}{% search
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}{% replace
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit{\adddot}}
  {}{}% <success> and <failure>

\begin{document}

\cite{grohmann1929paragraphos}

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Many thanks! And I appreciate the warning; it's just that some journals say they use Chicago but clearly (to judge from their examples and how citations appear in their articles) they in fact deviate in these minor ways from the Chicago style.

Comment: Occasionally, journals use issue numbers but not volumes. In those cases, the default `biblatex-chicago` format works well: it simply says *Past and Present* no. 100. But when using this answer, that case outputs "*Past and Present*.100"; is there a way to tweak this answer so that it says "*Past and Present* 100" (with no dot) instead? (Perhaps this should be a separate question, but I thought it might be a simple tweak to this one.)

Comment: @AlexRoberts Indeed, the Q&A format of the site works best for everyone if different requirements get their specific questions.

Comment: Great, thanks. I'll post this as a separate question.

Comment: I've posted it as a separate question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/474711/fixing-formatting-of-journals-with-only-issue-numbers-when-using-period-to-separ).