# Fixing formatting of journals with only issue numbers when using period to separate journal volume and issue number in biblatex-chicago

Tags: biblatex, biblatex-chicago

As a follow-up to an earlier [question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/473847/using-a-period-to-separate-volume-and-issue-number-of-a-journal-article-in-bibla) about how to customize `biblatex-chicago` to have it format a journal's volume and issue number as "`volume`.`number`", I would now like to know if there is a simple way to make to fix the output produced by @gusbrs's answer to that question.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{browning1964byz.scholarship,
    Author = {Browning, Robert},
    Journal = {Past \& Present},
    Number = {28},
    Pages = {3--20},
    Title = {Byzantine Scholarship},
    Year = {1964}}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

% solution from @gusbrs
\DeclareFieldFormat{journum}{#1}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}{% search
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}{% replace
  \printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
  \setunit{\adddot}}
  {}{}% <success> and <failure>

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\cite{browning1964byz.scholarship}

\end{document}
```

Current output is:

> Robert Browning, "Byzantine Scholarship," *Past & Present*.28 (1964): 3–20.

I would like it to become:

> Robert Browning, "Byzantine Scholarship," *Past & Present* 28 (1964): 3–20.

(space rather than period between journal title and issue number).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Only one small modification is needed: Use `\setunit*{\adddot}` instead of `\setunit{\adddot}`.

The starred version only inserts the punctuation command into the buffer if the last `\print...` command printed anything. In this case it will do nothing if no `volume` was printed, which means that the previous punctuation in the buffer survives and is printed.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago}

% solution from @gusbrs
\DeclareFieldFormat{journum}{#1}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibmacro{cjournal+ser+vol+num}
  {\printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
   \setunit{\addcomma\addspace}}
  {\printfield[jourvol]{volume}%
   \setunit*{\adddot}}
  {}{}% <success> and <failure>


\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{browning1964byz.scholarship,
  author  = {Browning, Robert},
  journal = {Past \& Present},
  number  = {28},
  pages   = {3--20},
  title   = {Byzantine Scholarship},
  year    = {1964},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{browning1964byz.scholarship}
\end{document}
```

[image: Robert Browning, “Byzantine Scholarship,” Past & Present 28 (1964): 3–20]

---

Looking at https://academic.oup.com/past/issue/28/1 there is an argument to be made here that the 28 is actually the `volume` and that all volumes have only one trivial (issue) `number`, namely `number = {1},`, which can be dropped. So the entry might look like

```
@article{browning1964byz.scholarship,
  author  = {Browning, Robert},
  journal = {Past \& Present},
  volume  = {28},
  pages   = {3--20},
  title   = {Byzantine Scholarship},
  year    = {1964},
}
```

which would remove the immediate need for the fix (which should still be retained, because it makes sense).

Comment: @AlexRoberts It *looks* simple in moewe's hands.  ;-)

Comment: Agreed! simple in that it involved a single additional character -- but certainly not simple in any other respect!