# Is there any difference between \setunit*{<punct>} and \setunit{\add<punct>}

Tags: biblatex, punctuation

For example, I would like to know what is the difference between :

- `\setunit*{\space}` (with `*` but without `add`)

and

- `\setunit{\addspace}` (without `*`, but with `add`).

I sometimes see the expression `\setunit*{\addspace}` (with both `*` and `add`) in the biblatex `.bbx` files. Is it not a bit redundant, since I believe that `*` and the `add` prefix have the same function, which is avoiding double punctuation ?

I am asking this question because I just redefined the @book driver in order to reverse the order of `edition` and `byeditor+other` macros. Then, in order to remove the comma, I replaced `\newunit\newblock` with `\setunit{\addspace}`. Which gave :

```
\printfield{edition}%
\setunit{\addspace}%
\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}%
```

At this moment, I started to ask myself whether I should or not add a `*`, as I sometimes see in those `.bbx` files.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The differences between `\setunit` and `\setunit*` and between `\addspace` and `\space` are completely orthogonal.

Before we get into the details of `biblatex`'s punctuation buffer, it is a good idea to understand the basics. There are very good examples in §4.11.7 *Using the Punctuation Tracker* of the [`biblatex` documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/biblatex/doc/biblatex.pdf) and I have written about it in various answers on this site, e.g. [What do \setunit and \newunit do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409148/35864), [biblatex: \DeclareCiteCommand adds semicolon between \printfield and \printnames, but only sometimes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/435162/35864), [Proper use of in:, \intitlepunct for @inbook entries in biblatex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/175730/35864). The main idea is that `biblatex` does not print punctuation marks directly when they are encountered in a `\setunit` command. Instead the punctuation is saved and then printed by the next `\printtex`, `\printfield`, `\printlist`, `\printnames`, `\printdate` command that prints anything. Later `\setunit`s override the punctuation from earlier `\setunit` calls. The punctuation buffer means that `biblatex` avoids double punctuation. It also means that you can usually avoid excessive `\iffieldundef{...}` calls when it comes to making sure punctuation looks right.

### `\setunit` vs `\setunit*`

When `biblatex` sees a `\setunit` it saves its argument in the punctuation buffer (overwriting its previous contents). The buffer is printed the next time `biblatex` encounters a `\print(text|field|list|names|date)` command that prints something.

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{A} }%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{B} }%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{C} }%
  \printdate}
```

When `biblatex` sees the `\setunit{ \textbf{B} }` it adds `\textbf{B}` to the buffer. Then it sees `\printfield{edition}`. If the edition field is not empty, `biblatex` will print the contents of the buffer and then the contents of the edition field. If the field is empty, nothing happens. Then `biblatex` sees the `\setunit{ \textbf{C} }` and adds  `\textbf{C}` to the buffer. Then `\printdate` prints the buffer and the date if the date is not empty and does nothing otherwise.

In particular we will see

> Appleby, Humphrey **A** *On the Importance of the Civil Service* **B** 4th ed. **C** 1980

if `author`, `title`, `edition` and `date` are present, but we get

> Bppleby, Humphrey **A** *On the Importance of the Civil Service* **C** 1981

if there is no `edition` field, because `\setunit` overwrites the buffer (so 'the last `\setunit` wins').

`\setunit*` works slightly differently: It will only add its argument to the punctuation buffer if the previous `\print(text|field|list|names|date)` command printed something.

With

```
\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{A} }%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{B} }%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit*{ \textbf{C} }%
  \printdate}
```

the same example entries from above will produce

> Appleby, Humphrey **A** *On the Importance of the Civil Service* **B** 4th ed. **C** 1980
>
> Bppleby, Humphrey **A** *On the Importance of the Civil Service* **B** 1981

That is to say in the Bppleby entry without `edition` we get a **B** and not a **C** like in the `\setunit` case.

That is because here `\setunit*{ \textbf{B} }` checks if `\printfield{edition}` printed something and only adds `\texbf{B}` to the buffer *if that is the case*. The second entry has no `edition` field, so the `\setunit*` after `\printfield{edition}` does nothing.

One common use for `\setunit*` is between fields that *usually* appear together, but where in exceptional circumstances the first field may be missing (if the second field is missing it doesn't really matter whether we use `\setunit` or `\setunit*` because a following `\setunit` will overwrite it anyway).

`standard.bbx` for example has

```
\newbibmacro*{series+number}{%
  \printfield{series}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \newunit}
```

That means that if both `series` and `number` are present, there is only a space between them. But if `series` is missing, there will not be a space before `number` but instead the previous content of the punctuation tracker.

Another example of the difference between `\setunit` and `\setunit*` is at [Fixing formatting of journals with only issue numbers when using period to separate journal volume and issue number in biblatex-chicago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/474711/35864).

### `\addspace` vs `\space`

`\addspace` is defined in `biblatex.sty` as

```
\newrobustcmd*{\addspace}{%
  \unspace\blx@postpunct
  \space\blx@imc@resetpunctfont}
```

Essentially that means that `\addspace` is `\space` which does some additional housekeeping.

In particular the `\unspace` means that `\addspace` tries to suppress any previous space before it inserts its own `\space`. This should help prevent spurious spaces. Compare (the bad example)

```
\printnames{author}
\setunit{\space}%
\printfield{title}%
```

and

```
\printnames{author}
\setunit{\addspace}%
\printfield{title}%
```

here the first line should read

```
\printnames{author}%
```

instead of `\printnames{author}`. But `\addspace` can still prevent the undesirable double space that `\space` would produce.

`\blx@postpunct` is an internal command that helps get American quotation marks right. In American quotation style the quotation mark may slip past a following punctuation even if it does not strictly speaking belong to the quotation itself. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quotation_marks_in_English#U.S._practice.)

`\blx@imc@resetpunctfont` is a part of `biblatex`'s code for the `punctfont` feature, which typesets punctuation in the same style as the previous text.

A similar thing holds for the other `\add...` punctuation commands `biblatex` defines. `\addcomma` produces a comma, tries to avoid spurious spaces, unwanted double punctuation and does some housekeeping.

Basically you always want to use `\addspace` instead of `\space` (`\addcomma` instead of `,`, `\addperiod` instead of `.`, etc. etc.), but it is not always easy to spot the difference (in particular if you use `%` to avoid spurious spaces, don't use the American quotation mark convention and don't activate `punctfont`).

There is just one situation in `biblatex` where `\space` is usually preferred over `\addspace`, namely when the space directly follows a different punctuation command in the same macro that already uses `\add...`. The usual idiom is

```
\setunit{\addcomma\space}%
```

instead of `\setunit{\addcomma\addspace}%` because the `\addcomma` already does all the necessary housekeeping so that there is nothing left to do for the space. Of course the same holds for `\addcolon\space`, `\addperiod\space` etc.

### Concluding remarks

I could not find a single instance of `\setunit*{\space}` in the `biblatex` standard styles, but I could find several `\setunit*{\addspace}`s. Even if you can't see a difference between `\setunit*{\space}` and `\setunit*{\addspace}` I would argue that `\addspace` is what you should use in almost all cases.

Whether you should use `\setunit` or `\setunit*` in the code quoted in the question depends on the behaviour you expect if the `edition` is missing.

### MWE for testing

```
\documentclass[british]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\usepackage[style=authoryear, backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareBibliographyDriver{book}{%
  \printnames{author} 
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{B} }%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{C} }%
  \printdate
  \setunit{\par}%
  \printnames{author} 
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \printfield{title}%
  \setunit{ \textbf{B} }%
  \printfield{edition}%
  \setunit*{ \textbf{C} }%
  \printdate}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@book{appleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Appleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1980},
  edition = {4},
}
@book{bppleby,
  author  = {Humphrey Bppleby},
  title   = {On the Importance of the Civil Service},
  date    = {1981},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\cite{appleby,bppleby}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```