# Period instead of comma for proceedings biblatex

Tags: biblatex, biber

The punctuation before the year in a proceedings is a period.

The punctuation before the year in an article is a comma.

Is there some parameter/argument to pass to biblatex/biber to make this punctuation uniform?

An example MWE, with some slight formatting choices.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mwepubs.bib}
% Removes months from citations
\AtEveryBibitem{\clearfield{month}}
\AtEveryCitekey{\clearfield{month}}

% Removes the ``In'' before journals/venues
\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

% Remove parentheses from years in articles
\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}% NEW
    \iffieldundef{issue}
      {\usebibmacro{date}}
      {\printfield{issue}%
       \setunit*{\addspace}%
       \usebibmacro{date}}% NEW
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{mwepubs.bib}
@article{Art1,
  title = {Article Title One},
  author = {Author One and Author Two},
  journal = {Best Journal},
  url = {http://www.google.com},
  year = {2021},
}
@inproceedings{Proc1,
  author       = {Again One and Again Two},
  title        = {Proceedings Title},
  booktitle    = {Venue where},
  pages        = {1--71},
  year         = {2018},
  doi          = {10.10000/1000},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{Art1}
\fullcite{Proc1}
\end{document}
```

This produces the output:

[image: image_with_mixed_periods_and_commas]

Note the comma before one year and a period before the other year.

Comment: Do you prefer the `,` or the `.`? You could change the `inproceedings` driver to use a comma `,` instead of a period by adding the following to your preamble: [code](https://pastebin.com/raw/KqWRfUR4) (change highlighted), [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jsz7e.png)

Comment: I was wanting the period before the year in the articles. Even more, I was hoping for a command to have periods before years after all journals/books/proceedings/etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Punctuation in `biblatex` is usually handled asynchronously by the punctuation buffer. Style code adds a punctuation mark to the buffer (overwriting its previous state) and the buffer is printed and emptied the next time a `biblatex` prints a field. This allows `biblatex` to avoid double punctuation and punctuation clashes. It also gives us a fairly straightforward way to force punctuation before a certain field. It's trickier to control the punctation after a field. For those who want to know more about the punctation buffer, I'll leave a link to [What do \setunit and \newunit do?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/409148/35864) and [Is there any difference between \setunit*{<punct>} and \setunit{\add<punct>}](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/538920/35864). The second post links to a number of further discussions of the punctuation buffer on this site.

The standard `biblatex` drivers mostly use `\newunitpunct` for punctuation between fields (this command can be redefined by the user, by default it's a period plus a sapce). There are, however, a couple of exceptions, for example we get `nametitledelim` between the author/editor (and year in `authoryear`-like styles) and the title and we get `\bibpagespunct` before the `pages` field. This makes customisation easier for users, because they can just redefine these delimiters or commands. We also get various (hard-coded) punctuation marks in the `publisher`+`location`+`date` block. These are harder to customise: Users need to redefine the involved bibmacros directly.

The standard styles also hard-code different punctuation in the `journal+issuetitle` and `volume+number+eid` bibmacros that typeset most journal information for `@article`s. In particular the publication year is typeset in parentheses and therefore usually preceded by just a space if the `volume` is present (I'm guessing because the year is seen as subordinate to the `volume` field). The relevant bibmacros look like this ([see `standard.bbx`, ll. 784-804 in v3.19](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/blob/24a94f8f608872e11d259d7c581fc90ea76542a5/tex/latex/biblatex/bbx/standard.bbx#L784-L804))

```
\newbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\newbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit*{\adddot}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\bibeidpunct}%
  \printfield{eid}}
```

In the standard styles there is no simple switch to make these punctuation marks the same. You'll have to redefine these bibmacros. The following might work (we just replace the `\setunit{\addspace}` before `\usebibmacro{issue+date}` in `journal+issuetitle` with `\setunit{\addperiod\space}`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}

\DeclareFieldInputHandler{month}{\def\NewValue{}}

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addperiod\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Art1,
  title   = {Article Title One},
  author  = {Author One and Author Two},
  journal = {Best Journal},
  url     = {http://www.google.com},
  year    = {2021},
}
@inproceedings{Proc1,
  author       = {Again One and Again Two},
  title        = {Proceedings Title},
  booktitle    = {Venue where},
  pages        = {1--71},
  year         = {2018},
  doi          = {10.10000/1000},
}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\begin{document}
\fullcite{Art1}

\fullcite{Proc1}
\end{document}
```

[image: Author One and Author Two. “Article Title One”. Best Journal. 2021. url: http://www.google.com Again One and Again Two. “Proceedings Title”. Venue where. 2018, pp. 1–71. doi: 10.10000/1000]